# Tomcat 9 takes 1 minute to stop

Tags: windows, tomcat, windows-services, tomcat9

I installed tomcat 9.0.14 on my system(Windows 10, Windows server 2016 R2)
I've no issue while starting the tomcat service(start in 2-3 sec).
However, it takes 1 minute to stop. 
I thought one of my project residing under webapps is taking time so I removed all my project but result is same.
After that I make it empty webapps folder empty to check further still tomcat took 1 min to stop. 
I check the log file and their are no errors.Tomcat is idle for 1 minute while stopping.

```
Common-deamon.log-------

[2019-01-08 16:30:02] [info]  [13948] Stopping service... 
[2019-01-08 16:30:03] [info]  [13948] Service stop thread completed.
[2019-01-08 16:31:03] [info]  [ 1940] Run service finished.
[2019-01-08 16:31:03] [info]  [ 1940] Commons Daemon procrun finished 

catalina.log--------

08-Jan-2019 16:30:02.399 INFO [Thread-6] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
08-Jan-2019 16:30:02.431 INFO [Thread-6] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
08-Jan-2019 16:30:02.453 INFO [Thread-6] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service [Catalina]
08-Jan-2019 16:30:02.453 INFO [Thread-6] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
08-Jan-2019 16:30:02.453 INFO [Thread-6] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
```

Is their any way I can reduce the sopping time of tomcat 9.
In tomcat 8 stopping time was 3-5 sec
Any help is appreciated.....

Comment: If your question is answered, please mark it answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was abel to reproduce this by

- Downloading and extracting the `apache-tomcat-9.0.14-windows-x64.zip`
- cd to `apache-tomcat/bin`
- `service.bat install`
- Starting the Service is quick, stopping it delays exactly 60 seconds.

This seemes to be an issue of Tomcat, but current [developer snapchot (trunk) changelog](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/9.0.15/webapps/docs/changelog.xml#L84-L85) suggests it has been already fixed for not yet released Tomcat 9.0.15+ without explicit bug report assigned:

**Tomcat 9.0.15 (markt) in development / Catalina:**

> Correct a bug exposed in 9.0.14 and ensure that the Tomcat terminates in a timely manner when running as a service. (markt)

Comment: Thanks Selaron...Do you have any idea when they are planning to release 9.0.15? Is the same working in 9.0.13 version??

Comment: As it is said to be "a bug exposed in 9.0.14" I'd consider any earlier version not affected by this. Steps to reproduce are trivial, just try it out.

Comment: 9.0.15 should be released in February.

Comment: In Tomcat 9.0.29 the problem is still present, so if they fixed it in 9.0.15 they might have lost the changes in later versions

Comment: I have tried Tomcat 9.0.41, the problem is still present. Can anyone please suggest how I can resolve it? in tomcat 8 my application stop at 20 Sec only but in tomcat 9 same application takes 70 sec.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem with Tomcat v9.0.26. Tomcat took exactly 60 seconds to finish once you terminated the server. We tried hard to close and shutdown everything we had in our application and in the end we realized we had a ThreadPoolExecutor that created a newCachedThreadPool() and this cachepool has a **"keepAliveTime" of 60 seconds**.

So after terminating the tomcat the threadpool was waiting 60 seconds to check if the threads are still needed to be reused. Only after this time it really shut down. So the solution was to shut down the cached thread pool once we shut down the application.